# Copy PIL image into clipboard (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I've made a little Paint program in Python with Tkinter and now I want to add a "Copy" function, so you can CTRL + V your drawing faster in other apps like Discord or whatever. Here's a test:

```
def Copy():
def send_to_clipboard(clip_type, data):
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    win32clipboard.EmptyClipboard()
    win32clipboard.SetClipboardData(clip_type, data)
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

x2 = fen.winfo_rootx()+Can.winfo_x()
y2 = fen.winfo_rooty()+Can.winfo_y()
x1 = x2+Can.winfo_width()
y1 = y2+Can.winfo_height()
print("save")
ImageGrab.grab().crop((x2,y2,x1,y1)).save("Image.bmp")

filepath = "Image.bmp"
image = Image.open(filepath)

output = io.BytesIO()
image.convert("RGB")
image.save(output, "BMP")
data = output.getvalue()[8:]
output.close()

send_to_clipboard(win32clipboard.CF_DIB, data)
```

When I try this it works, except that I can't paste the image into Paint or Discord...
Or it can't read it, or it crashes.
Can someone help me please? ;-;

Comment: I do not think you can save the `Image` to a `StringIO`. Try some kind of binary (bytes) buffer.

Comment: Use `BytesIO` and also save the image as `bmp` format instead of `png`

Comment: In the meanwhile I saw another post on this and it worked. But now as I try to copy it into other softwares it doesn't work... Paint can't recognize it and Discord crashes when I CTRL + V it...